# Chrome extension manifest matches How to only match base URL, no subpages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension for Twitter and only want it to affect pages on twitter.com but not affect subpages(i.e. twitter.com/mentions).

My manifest is currently set as the following, but still affects subpages.

`"matches": ["http://www.twitter.com/","https://twitter.com/"],`

Any ideas?

Comment: As per the documentation your url matching pattern is looking invalid. You will need to use a pattern like this *://*.twitter.com/* and/or *://twitter.com/* However, you can check for the exact url you want your script to work on and achieve your goal

Comment: @elegant-user [The documentations](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns) shows "http://example.org/foo/bar.html" as a valid path. Including the http protocol is valid.

Comment: If it is correct your goal is achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You want it to affect pages on twitter.com" - From that I assume that your content script is updating  UI.

Now, if you start with the content script on main Page (twitter.com) you can achieve that but when you click on links on the page two things are possible -

1) Entire page is refreshed e.g. when you click on Links in "Who to follow" on right side.

2) Page is not refreshed, and only page content is changed e.g when you click on Moments, Notifications etc.

In second scenario when page is not refreshed then your content scripts are not refreshed as the page is not reloaded.

And most links in Twitter does not update the full page, so going by this approach won't help you much in case of Twitter.

However, you can use tab update event handler in background.js where you will get to know every update on tab url change.

```
let tabUpdateHandler = (tabId, {url: updatedUrl, status}, tab) => {
    if (updatedUrl == "https://twitter.com/") {
        // do anything with your extension here. like enable/disable your extension, message content script for any update etc.
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(tabUpdateHandler);
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: So I think you are saying that in some cases, clicking on a link (notifications) does not always take me to a different page, but rather updates the content on the already loaded page, with new fetched data (but still updates the URL in the bar), which is why my extension is still working on different "pages".  I was not aware of any of that so thank you. I will look up how tabUpdateHandler works and update my code to address my issues. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You are welcome.
Do let me know if I could be of any further help to you. And if you think this answer is helpful to you, please mark this as a solution.

Thank you.